# WPF ListBoxItems problem

Tags: wpf, styles, listboxitems

In wpf app I have binded Dictionary to listbox. I have own style on listbox.
Listbox item consit image and 3 texblocks.

Friend class is here:

```
public class FriendData
{
    public string idUser { get; set; }
    public string nick { get; set; }
    public string sefNick { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string photo { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public string isFriend { get; set; }

    public string blockQuote { get; set; }

    public FriendData(string idUser, string nick, string sefNick, string status, string photo, string sex, string isFriend)
    {
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.nick = nick;
        this.sefNick = sefNick;
        this.status = status;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.isFriend = isFriend;
    }
}
```

ListBox style is here:

```
    <Style x:Key="friendsListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Value.photo}" Margin="4,4,4,2"/>
                        <Grid Name="SlaveGrid" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Name="tbName" Text="{Binding Value.nick}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,2,2" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Medium"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="tbBlockQuote" Text="{Binding Value.blockQuote}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="DarkGray"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="tbStatus" Text="{Binding Value.status}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="MainGrid">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.35" ScaleY="1.35" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>-->
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

My first problem is, tbStatus is binded to property status of class Friend. Status can have only 3 values : 0,1,2. If status have value 0, I need set tbStatus.Text="Offline", if status have value 1, I need set tbStatus.Text="Online" and if status is 2 then must be tbStatus.Text="Just Log". Its possible this condition set from XAML in listBox style?

```
<TextBlock Name="tbStatus" Text="{Binding Value.status}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
```

My second problem is if status is 0, I need convert Image to grayscale. I have func wich make converting to grayscale. I would like set these condition in listBox style. Any advance?

Here is :

```
private void ConvertImageToGrayScaleImage(string uri)

{

    Image grayImage = new Image();

    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();

    bmpImage.BeginInit();

    bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(uri);

    bmpImage.EndInit();

    FormatConvertedBitmap grayBitmap = new FormatConvertedBitmap();

    grayBitmap.BeginInit();

    grayBitmap.Source = bmpImage;

    grayBitmap.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray8;

    grayBitmap.EndInit();

    grayImage.Source = grayBitmap;

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(grayImage);

}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, and very little question.  Can you trim out code until you have a minimal set that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, your best bet is to write an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

For instance, here is one for converting your text:

```
public class StatusToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int status = Int32.Parse(value.ToString());
        switch (status)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Offline";

            case 1:
                return "Online";

            case 2:
                return "Just Log"; 
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string status = value.ToString();
        switch (status)
        {
            case "Offline":
                return 0;

            case "Online":
                return 1;

            case "Just Log":
                return 2; 
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

And your Text binding becomes (after adding the reference in an appropriate Resources section of your XAML):

```
 <TextBlock Name="tbStatus" 
            Text="{Binding Value.status,
                           Converter={StaticResource statusToText}}"
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            Margin="2,2,2,2" 
            FontSize="11" 
            FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
```

I'll leave the image converter to you, since this is basic stuff, and it would essentially be a repeat of this code.

Note that this is hard-coding values, which isn't really a Best Practice.  You should probably be using enumerations, as well as resources (instead of hard-coded strings) if you ever plan to localize this app.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advance is very helpfull for me, I am newbie in WPF. Have a nice day

Comment: @Tom - no problem.  FYI - I've noticed that you haven't marked any answers to your questions as answers (although you may very well have voted them up, which is good).  If the answers given to your questions have actually helped you solve the problems, check the checkmark as an answer - as you ask more questions, people may be more willing to give you answers if you have a positive reputation.